# Who is responsible for "blinding" a paper for double-blind review?

Tags: journals, peer-review, paper-submission, journal-workflow, anonymity

Is it my responsibility as author to remove author and affiliation before submitting the paper to a journal?

In my opinion it is, but then I read [this blog article](https://www.elsevier.com/connect/8-reasons-i-rejected-your-article) by an Editor-in-Chief of some Elsevier journal who lists several reasons for rejecting a paper, including:

> The manuscript is not complete; it may be lacking key elements such as the title, authors, affiliations, [..].

So my paper can be rejected if I prepared it for double-blind review myself? But how can I make sure that the paper is properly reviewed without my name and affiliation?

Comment: Why do you think the editor is referring to a double blind review process, in that article?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will depend on the journal, and if the journal follows double-blind review, they will tell you how to properly format your paper. For example, the *American Journal of Epidemiology*:

> Manuscripts must be submitted online in a double-spaced, blinded format, with pages numbered, in at least 12-point type, do not insert line numbers.
>
> When uploading the manuscript to the Web site, please delete any text reference to the paper's authors, affiliations, and acknowledgments.

Comment: And what if there is no such hint? For example nothing stated here: http://jbhi.embs.org/for-authors/prepare-and-submit-your-manuscript/ ... Okay, I can always ask the Editor-in-Chief...

Comment: @DocBrown I see no reason to believe that journal follows double-blind reviews.